# Adding Header Page in Itextsharp when the value is from gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itext

I want to make convert gridview to pdf, the code is run well, but iam confused how to make headerpage (not header column) on it, ill try to use stringbuilder but when i tried the gridview is not view in pdf, i also tried other way but still dont know how to make it works,
maybe u can teach me how to make it works?

in this code i tried to use chunk, but the chunk isnot show :(

```
    protected void btnConvertPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        gridconvertPDF.AllowPaging = false;

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ClientList.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        HtmlForm hf = new HtmlForm();
        gridconvertPDF.Parent.Controls.Add(hf);
        hf.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
        hf.Controls.Add(gridconvertPDF);
        hf.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        Chunk c = new Chunk
        ("PEMINJAMAN INVENTARIS  \n",
        FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 25));
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        p.Add(c);
        Chunk chunk1 = new Chunk
        ("Rizki Asriningtyas \n",
        FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 8));
        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
        p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        p1.Add(chunk1);
        pdfDoc.Add(p);
        pdfDoc.Add(p1);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);

        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();}
```

Comment: You associate a `PdfWriter` only *after* you added all the header content to `pdfDoc`. Thus, all that header content got lost. You should first create a `Document`, then associate a `PdfWriter`, then open the document, then add content to the document.

Comment: Yeay its works, thankyou soo much :)

Answer (score 1):

my fault is make pdfwriter after add all the header content to pdf, here is the right code

```
  protected void btnConvertPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridconvertPDF.AllowPaging = false;

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ClientList.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    HtmlForm hf = new HtmlForm();
    gridconvertPDF.Parent.Controls.Add(hf);
    hf.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
    hf.Controls.Add(gridconvertPDF);
    hf.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    Chunk c = new Chunk
    ("PEMINJAMAN INVENTARIS  \n",
    FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 25));
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    p.Add(c);
    Chunk chunk1 = new Chunk
    ("Rizki Asriningtyas \n",
    FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 8));
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
    p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
    p1.Add(chunk1);
    pdfDoc.Add(p);
    pdfDoc.Add(p1);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);

    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();}
```